# Meeting required income for a UK unmarried partner visa while living outside the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, uk-visa, uk-citizens

I'm a UK citizen. I have been living with my partner in her home country for a few years now. I'd like to go back to the UK to study, so we're looking at getting her an unmarried partner visa to come to the UK.

One of the requirements is to be earning 18,600 GBP per year. I meet that requirement currently, but moving back to the UK will necessarily involve leaving my job here (and thus, losing my income).

Are visa judges sympathetic to this? I'm confident I can find an equally paying, UK based job once I'm residing back in the UK, but not before.